# Discrete Mathematics - Lattices and boolean Algebra

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

Let $A$ be the set of all $2\times2$ boolean matrices and $R$ be a relation defined on $A$ as $M \mathrel{R} N$ if and only if $m_{ij} \leqslant n_{ij}$, where $1 \leqslant i, j \leqslant 2$. Is $(A,R)$ a lattice? Justify.

I am unable to solve the above question. I already know the following: There are 16 elements in set $A$. Now when i try to calculate relation $R$ according to the given conditions i am getting 81 pairs in relation $R$. Drawing a hasse diagram and calculating **least upper bound** and **greatest lower bound** for each point in the hasse diagram will go too lengthy. Is there a better method to do this?? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your structure is simply ${\Bbb B}^4$, the product of four copies of the Boolean lattice ${\Bbb B} = \{0, 1\}$, ordered by $0 \leqslant 1$. Thus, yes, $(A, R)$ is a lattice.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two matrices $A=\{a_{ij}:0\leq i,j\leq1\}$ and $B=\{b_{ij}:0\leq i,j\leq1\}$, then
$$A \wedge B = C = \{c_{ij}:0\leq i,j\leq1\}$$
and
$$A\vee B = D =\{d_{ij}:0\leq i,j\leq1\},$$
where
$$c_{ij}=\min\{a_{ij},b_{ij}\}$$
and
$$d_{ij}=\max\{a_{ij},b_{ij}\}.$$
This also forms a Boolean algebra, with
$$A' =\{1- a_{ij}:0\leq i,j\leq1\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $\{ L_\alpha \}$ is a family of lattices, then the Cartesian product $\prod_{\alpha} L_{\alpha}$ also has the structure of a lattice given by $\mathbf{x} \wedge \mathbf{y} = (x_\alpha \wedge y_\alpha)_{\alpha}$, $\mathbf{x} \vee \mathbf{y} = (x_\alpha \vee y_\alpha)_{\alpha}$ for $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}$ in the product. This fact, although obvious, is actually very convenient as it allows you to point out complicated lattices as the product of less-complicated ones, or as sublattices of the product of less-complicated lattices. (If you are interested, Google "Dilworth's Embedding Theorem.")

Sometimes is is useful to indentify matrices with elements in *blank* as a product of *blank* the number of entries in such matrices times. You see this in many areas of mathematics. Lie group theory comes to mind. If you want to think about $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ as a space, then you can think about how it sits inside $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.